# Not able to add a mesh plane into the autodesk viewer with three.js in Linux?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to add a mesh into the Forge viewer using Three.js. I used the same code and I was able to add the plane in windows but not in Linux.

The minimum code to replicate the problem is below.

```
  const drawingMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00 } );
  const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(400, 200);
  const texturePlane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, drawingMaterial);
  texturePlane.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  texturePlane.position.z = 0

  this.viewer.impl.sceneAfter.add(texturePlane);
```

Comment: The only difference between Linux and Windows could be the browser you use, but even here it is all or nothing. Which browser you use under Linux?

Try this example https://apprentice3d.github.io/SD226781-Samples/02.html (and activate the extension) under Linux.
If it works, then the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: What browser is yours? Did you try Chrome which has a pretty solid implementation of WebGL across the platforms? Code compatibility with THREE/Viewer actually has little to do with the OS but rather hinges on the browser's renderer.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering. I am using Chrome in both Linux and Windows.  I was able to pin point the problem further. The problem is when I try  to add the plane to the sceneAfter, when I switched to add the plane to scene, the code worked. However, I would like to add the plane to the sceneAfter, does anyone have any idea?